# how to get index of hash table when use double hashing and rehashing in c?

Tags: c, hash, hashtable, hash-function, double-hashing

I wrote a program to create hash table to user username and encrypted password. When inserting to the hash table, I use a double hash function to get the key. I have two hash functions. That is when call first hash function I got an index. If it contains no elements, I insert to that index. If it contains data, I call a second hash function to get the index. After all successful insertions, I store into a file. Then, I use rehashing (double the size) to increase my hash table size when more than users coming.

My logic is when I load the server, it inserts all data inside file to the hash table. But I have some doubt. I am using username as key to get index. When I insert all data from file to hash table, how can I find the index? (The confusion is about double hashing.) After inserting, I want to validate client username with an existing username. How can I get the particular user data for this? (I am not storing any keys to the file.) So how can I get that key? (The problem here is also double hashing.)

I want to do this with double hashing. I know to get details when I use a single hash function (pass username as key to retrieve index). But I want to avoid collisions using double hashing. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to store the key.

Comment: Why are you sure than double hashing will avoid collisions ? If you find an element by hash you have to check if the username are the same (the string not the hash)